# Is there a way to simulate a mouse click in under 1 ms?

Tags: c#, winapi, mouseevent, user32, sendinput

I am attempting to make a program which needs to be able to move the cursor to and click on pre-defined coordinates on the screen with minimal latency.

What I have done, is use pinvoke to access the functions SetCursorPos and mouse_event from user32.dll

However, when I use a stopwatch to time how long these functions take, SetCursorPos is about 2ms and mouse_event is about 30 or more milliseconds. I would like to know if there is anyway to do this faster?

There is a library for improving the performance of interop called AdvancedDLSupport. I was considering that and even emailed the author of the github repo, but in the reply I was told that for what I'm doing the real bottleneck is more likely to be the windows input queue itself.

So, is there anyway to prioritise the mouse_event to be at the top of that queue and hopefully be executed in less than a millisecond? I really have no idea if this is even possible, and if it is then it's not well documented as I couldn't find any information about this online.

I'm just a newbie programmer and even knowing where to begin to figure out how to do this is a little beyond the scope of my knowledge, and is probably difficult even for an expert programmer if it's even possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far(This is just one class within a larger program):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace NetMQ_test_project
{

    public class AutoClicker
    {
        //invoking DLLs to have access to GetCursorPos, SetCursorPos, mouse_event 
        //from windows API
        //naming conventions are not standard for C#
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

        public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
        public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

        private static POINT _buyPos;
        private static POINT _sellPos;

        public bool Executed = false;

        private static POINT SetPos()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Move cursor to desired position and press the S key to set. (Don't minimize this window)");
            POINT nullPoint = new POINT();
            if(Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.S)
            {
                GetCursorPos(out POINT point);
                return point;
            }
            else
            {
                return nullPoint;
            }
        }

        public static void SetBuyPos()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting Buy Position...");
            _buyPos = SetPos();
            Console.WriteLine("Buy Pos: {0},{1}", _buyPos.X, _buyPos.Y);
        }
        public static void SetSellPos()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting Sell Position...");
            _sellPos = SetPos();
            Console.WriteLine("Sell Pos: {0},{1}",_sellPos.X,_sellPos.Y);
        }

        public static void Click()
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        //[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static void ClickBuy()
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            SetCursorPos(_buyPos.X, _buyPos.Y);
            sw.Stop();
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            sw.Stop();
            sw.Reset();
            //mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            //Click(); changed to be in-line to improve performance. Less elegant but whatever

            //Console.WriteLine("Buy Pos: {0},{1}", _buyPos.X, _buyPos.Y);
        }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static void ClickSell()
        {
            SetCursorPos(_sellPos.X, _sellPos.Y);
            Click();
            //Console.WriteLine("Sell Pos: {0},{1}", _sellPos.X, _sellPos.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `mouse_event()` is deprecated, use [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.  But note that [simulated events are not processed in real-time](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773) no matter which approach you take. So no, you are likely not going to get the kind of precision you want when simulating mouse events.

Comment: What you are testing is the speed of function execution, not the speed of application response. You cannot specify the time required for function execution.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to click on a button. [Notification Messages from Buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-messages#notification-messages-from-buttons): *When the user clicks a button, its state changes, and the button sends notification codes, in the form of WM_COMMAND messages, to its parent window. For example, a push button control sends the BN_CLICKED notification code whenever the user chooses the button.* you could try to send the message.

Comment: Yes I am trying to click on a button but it's on an external application, not the same program so I cannot access the button's state.

Comment: As for simulated events not being processed in real time, is there some kind of low-level way of directly updating the raw input thread? Or is that impossible?

Comment: @JonathonQuick there are ways to get a button's state across process boundaries. UI Automation, for instance. And no, you can't access the Raw Input thread. You can get notifications from it (via the `WM_INPUT` message), but you can't update it. You can only post simulated events to it.

Comment: .NET encompasses non-deterministic garbage collection. A consequence of this design is, that you do not get predictable performance characteristics for *anything*. Even if the system allowed you to inject input with your required latency, .NET would not be able to reliably take advantage of that.